# UITableView Automatically Select Row

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, row

When a `UITableView` loads, I want the only row, in the only section, to be selected so that the code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will execute immediately when the user loads the `UITableView`. I've tried the code below but it doesn't execute the code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` section. Any thoughts?

```
NSIndexPath *indexedPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexedPath animated:YES scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of this code.This will Automatically call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when the view is loaded.

```
  [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
```

Comment: I cannot make use of that code because the user has to physically tap the row for the underlying code to execute. The goal is to have the code execute when the view is loaded.

Comment: Okay..u mean to say didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not getting called on user tap?

Comment: Welcome buddy! Enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call some functionality which you are using in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can make a separate method and put all logic of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in your seperate method and then  call that method from both `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and wherever else you want to call the same code?

And If you want to additionally trigger event in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, you need to manually call the delegate method, it won't happen automatically:

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:your_indexpath];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Swift

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .bottom)
tableView.delegate?.tableView?(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
```